# How to open multiple servers parallel in zsh

Tags: zsh

I'm planning to open multiple servers in parallel on `zsh` like regular bash as below.

```
csshx host-lcb0[1-5].corp.com
```

---

```
[user@user.local ~]$ csshx host-lcb0[1-5].corp.com
zsh: no matches found: host-lcb0[1-5].corp.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax: `[1-5]` is a filename generation pattern matching one digit between 1 and 5, among the files in your current directory. There is likely no file with name i.e. `host-lcb02.corp.com` in your working directory.

You want to generate 5 arguments to csshx. This can be done by writing `{1..5}` instead.

Comment: Of course it does, and it does not matter what terminal application you run, as long as you use the correct shell. Maybe you can then accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

For `csshx` to work in zsh, you need to wrap it in quotes. This was not needed with bash, and I presume this has something to do with how zsh handles wildcards.

`csshx "host-lcb0[1-5].corp.com"`